# Complex polynomials agree on the unit circle implies they differ by a scalar multiple

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p,q\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ and $p,q\neq 0$. Suppose $\deg{p} = \deg{q}$ and roots of $p$ and $q$ all lie in the open unit disk. If $|p(z)|=|q(z)|$ for all $|z| = 1$, show that $q=cp$ where $c\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|c|=1$.

Attempt:

Let $g(z)=\dfrac{zq(\dfrac{1}{z})}{p(\dfrac{1}{z})}$. Then, $g(0)=0$. Also, for all $|z|\leq 1$, $p(\frac{1}{z})\neq 0$, hence $g$ is well-defined and analytic on the unit disk.

In order to use Schwarz lemma, ***it remains to show that $|g(z)|\leq 1$ on the open unit disk***. Assuming that, since $|g(z)| = |z|$ on the unit circle, $g$ is a rotation and $g(z) = cz$ where $|c|=1$.
Hence,
\begin{align}
g(z)&=\frac{zq(\dfrac{1}{z})}{p(\dfrac{1}{z})}\\
&=cz\\
\implies q &= cp
\end{align}
But I am not quite sure, actually I have no clue of how to show $|g(z)|\leq 1$ on the open unit disk.

Comment: $|z|=1$ implies $|\frac{1}{z}|=1$, so by hypothesis $|g(z)|=1$ on the unit disc, so by maximum modulus you get what you want

Comment: @Conrad I don't really see that. Can you explain a little bit more? Certainly, $|g(z)|=1$ on the unit circle, but how do we know that for any point on the unit disk $|g(z)|$ is also less than 1?

Comment: maximum modulus for analytic functions

Comment: Ahh. You mean the one where analytic functions attain its maximum at the boundary of a bounded open set. Thank you.

Comment: happy to be of help - you solved the problem nicely as indeed that is the standard way to do it